# Android custom calendar view multiple dates

Tags: android, calendarview

[image]

Good day to all of you, I am having a problem with android calendar view, my goal is to display multiple dates in android's calendar view, is there anyway that I can achieve it? It is for my case study. Thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: nothing but a more than one month display in dialog is it right?

Comment: No sir, my problem is, I need to make the default calendar view display multiple dates or a range of dates, like in the picture I need to highlight August 5 - August 10. Something like that sir. thanks

Comment: look this link may be its same as your requirement https://github.com/square/android-times-square

Comment: I dont know whether you requirement is feasible with android calender view, you can do this using third party library like [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) , [android-times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)

Comment: thank you very much sir @VishalHalani I will look into it and I will comeback if there is a problem or a development in my project. thanks to all of you ! :)

Comment: Caldroid is definitely the answer to my problem! thanks to all of youu! :)

Answer (score 0):

using setMaxDate and SetMinDate methods on date picker you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Caldroid library to achieve this funcnality
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid